# Loading a DOT file using RGL

Tags: ruby, dot, ruby-rgl

RGL supports writing DOT files from a graph, is it possible to create a graph from a DOT file?

*(Obviously I can parse the DOT file myself and create a graph, but I'm wondering if this functionality exists already).*

Comment: See `graph_from_dotfile(file)` in the examples.  http://rgl.rubyforge.org/rgl/files/examples/examples_rb.html

Comment: @onionjake. Thanks for the link, the example is a start. Ideally, I'd like the library to support this conversion (with properties as well as edges).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install graphviz which gives you the 'dot' command.
Then you can run

```
dot -Tpng graph.dot > output.png
```

but I found that after installing dot the rgl method write_to_graphic_file automatically writes the image if you do something like

```
graph_obj.write_to_graphic_file('png')
```

Comment: Um, I don't mean an image of the graph. In your example, I want to load graph_obj from a dot file.